# Why isn't my bot responding to anything ? ( discord.py )

Tags: discord, discord.py

Im making a ds bot in python I've already made some other simple bot but this time, I'm stuck.
It just outputs ready then nothing not even in the log.txt file.

CODE :

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commmands.Bot(command_prefix="*")
f = open("log.txt",mode="w")

def log(command_used,user):
    print(f"{user} used the {command_used} command")
    f.write(f"{user} -> {command_used}")

# bot

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("READY")

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    print("a")
    log("test","idk")

bot.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a little bit deaper, I found out that I didn't activate the intents on the discord dev portal